# Had the climatologists predicted climate change as the deviations to both extremely cold and hot temperatures before?

Tags: climate, climate-change, earth-observation, snow

Recently [I read](http://grist.org/article/leaping-blizzards-global-warming-produces-bigger-snowfalls/) that the current extreme snowfall in northern temperate climate is caused by the increased evaporation due to the global warming.

Had any scientist predicted these extremes before they've been observed?

I've found nothing about such predictions in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_climate_change_science#Scientists_increasingly_predict_warming.2C_1970s).

Comment: extreme weather events are definitely part of the IPCC reports

Comment: @farrenthorpe Thanks, you're right. Btw in the meantime I got the idea how to test if the first thing were scientists trying to explain the unexpected data or media spreading the non-accurate term "global warming": via the [Google NGram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=climate+change%2C+global+warming&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclimate%20change%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglobal%20warming%3B%2Cc0) Of course, it matches what you've written.

Comment: Err... What extreme snowfall is that?  Admittedly, we're actually having a decent winter hereabouts after several years of drought, but it's in no way abnormal.  Likewise for news I see from other temperate climate areas.

Comment: @jamesqf The same applies for the Central Europe where I live. But the news I quoted come from the data from the northern temperate climate area.

Comment: @Probably: Well, that link is looking just at the northeastern US - not even Canada! - which is hardly the entire northern temperate climate.  You also have to remember that it's a news article, and news isn't news unless it's somehow out of the ordinary.  Who'd look at an article that said "this is just a typical winter snowfall, folks"?

Comment: @jamesqf Also, the linked article is about [Jan 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_2014_North_American_cold_wave), right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change summarizes the state of scientific understanding of climate change every few years and at least as far back as 2002 has projected a range of changes in extreme weather.

In the IPCC report for 2002, the Working Group II: Impacts, Adaptation and Vulnerability summarized the existing scientific understanding in may areas, including "Climate Variability and Extreme Events":
"Most studies of climate change impacts have focused on changes in mean climate conditions. However, global climate change is likely to bring changes in climate variability and extreme events as well. This is relevant here because decisionmakers often consider hedging strategies to be prepared for the possibility of low-probability but high-consequence events -- a risk management framework.  Features of projected changes in extreme weather and climate events in the 21st century include more frequent heat waves, less frequent cold spells (barring so-called singular events), **greater intensity of heavy rainfall events**, more frequent midcontinental summer drought, greater intensity of tropical cyclones, and more intense El Nino-Southern Oscillation (ENSO) events." -
[Climate Variability and Extreme Events](https://www.ipcc.ch/ipccreports/tar/wg2/index.php?idp=61#1434)

The question is also addressed in section 2.5. "Projected Changes in Climate Extremes could have Major Consequences":

> The vulnerability of human societies and natural systems to climate
>   extremes is demonstrated by the damage, hardship, and death caused by
>   events such as droughts, floods, heat waves, avalanches, and
>   windstorms. While there are uncertainties attached to estimates of
>   such changes, **some extreme events are projected to increase in
>   frequency and/or severity during the 21st century** due to changes in
>   the mean and/or variability of climate, so it can be expected that the
>   severity of their impacts will also increase in concert with global
>   warming (see Figure SPM-2). Conversely, the frequency and magnitude of
>   extreme low temperature events, such as cold spells, is projected to
>   decrease in the future, with both positive and negative impacts.

Answer (score 1):

Increased snowfall in a year or for a few years is weather, not climate change.  Reports such as "this storm" or "this season" being cause by, proving or disproving global warming are all anecdotal and serve no purpose other than to fuel those who do not understand the concepts but want ammunition to fight for their point of view to claim global warming as fact or fraud.

Global climate change, either towards warming or cooling promotes weather extremes.  Warming will cause change.  Some places will become colder while on average temperatures will rise.  Droughts, in general will increase, while some places will flood.  Storms though in general are all expected to be stronger.

Comment: Also, in some places (like the Sierra Nevada) the normal pattern seems to be to cycle between very dry spells like the last 5 years or so, and very wet/snowy ones like we seem to be having (so far) this year.  So the average is not what we normally get.

Answer (score 0):

The article states snowmageddon 2010. 2010 was in the low phase of the 11 year sunspot cycle. 2016-7 were in the high phase and have been the hottest years on record. Snow is only precipitation, precipitation is expected to be less predictable and subject to more extremes of drought and high rainfall. If you want to learn more about that, read about global warming causing destabilized and extreme weather.

A better reason for snowmaggedon is this:
[image]

[image]